# Threshold for quantum Repetition Code

Tags: error-correction, information-theory, fault-tolerance

I'm learning about the Threshold theorem but I struggle with the computations of the threshold which are usually presented (even the one in the book by Nielsen & Chuang). To clear my head, I would therefore like to compute the threshold in the following simple case:

- Repetition code on 3-qubit
- Only qubit flip errors, happening with probability `q`.

How can I precisely compute this value?

Answer (score 2):

The threshold is relative to the noise model and the decoder that you are using. In general you can't compute it analytically, you can only estimate it numerically.

If you have the right tools available, the simplest way to estimate the threshold is to just simulate running the circuit under various levels of noise and see how often decoding succeeds at various code distances. You then look for the level of noise above which more code distance is hurtful instead of helpful. For example, you can do this using Stim for simulation and PyMatching for decoding. In fact, one of the tasks covered as an example in [Stim's getting started tutorial](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/813856a61e6c6109c4a230e907bbfd5ac8bf0cab/doc/getting_started.ipynb) is estimating the threshold of the repetition code.